# How many battleships has Zapp Brannigan lost?

Tags: futurama

How many starships/battleships has Captain Zapp Brannigan lost that were under his direct control, throughout the course of Futurama's seasons and films?

Comment: In fact that 42 is the Answer Tor everything, i would say he lost 42 Ships so far.

Comment: He hasn't lost any ships, he knows exactly where each of them crashed.

Comment: i'd rather ask how many ships he has not lost

Comment: I think that the correct answer is "all of them".

Answer (score 12):

If we count a "loss" as every time a ship is seriously damaged or destroyed (meaning that a *repaired* ship can count more than once) then I count 8 losses:

- [The Nimbus](http://theinfosphere.org/Nimbus), the intergalactic flagship of the [DOOP](http://theinfosphere.org/Democratic_Order_of_Planets) fleet, was seriously damaged or destroyed a total of 5 times:

  - It was cut in half during the [Decapodian invasion](http://theinfosphere.org/Decapodian_invasion_of_Earth) in ["A Taste of Freedom"](http://theinfosphere.org/A_Taste_of_Freedom).
  - It was shot down by the [remote-controlled solid gold Death Stars](http://theinfosphere.org/Remote-controlled_solid_gold_Death_Stars) during the [Battle for Earth](http://theinfosphere.org/Battle_for_Earth,_3007) in [*Bender's Big Score*](http://theinfosphere.org/Bender%27s_Big_Score).
  - It was sliced in two while chasing the [Feministas](http://theinfosphere.org/Feministas) through Leo Wong's "miniature" golf course in [*Into the Wild Green Yonder*](http://theinfosphere.org/Into_the_wild_green_yonder).
  - It crashed into the already-crashed [Planet Express ship](http://theinfosphere.org/Planet_Express_ship) in ["Rebirth"](http://theinfosphere.org/Rebirth).
  - It crashed into the ground in ["Fun on a Bun"](http://theinfosphere.org/Fun_on_a_Bun) during the battle with the Neanderthals.
- [The Titanic](http://theinfosphere.org/Titanic), which was swallowed by a black hole in ["A Flight to Remember"](http://theinfosphere.org/A_Flight_to_Remember).
- The restaurant Le Palm d'Orbit, which crashed into the planet [Amazonia](http://theinfosphere.org/Planet_Amazonia) in ["Amazon Women in the Mood"](http://theinfosphere.org/Amazon_Women_in_the_Mood). *"She's built like a steak house, but she handles like a Bistro."*
- [The Tiny One-man Stealth Fighter](http://theinfosphere.org/Tiny_One-Man_Stealth_Fighter), which crashed on [Lo'ihi Island](http://theinfosphere.org/Lo%27ihi_Island) when attempting to destroy [the mighty V-GINY](http://theinfosphere.org/V-GINY) in ["In-A-Gadda-Da-Leela"](http://theinfosphere.org/In-A-Gadda-Da-Leela).

In addition, you *could* count the stone Martian ship from ["A Farewell to Arms"](http://theinfosphere.org/A_Farewell_to_Arms) seeing as how Zapp had it *purposefully dismantled*, but that was *after* he successfully piloted and landed it on Mars.

Comment: *Leela* was piloting the 'The Tiny One-man Stealth Fighter'.  Zap was just a back-seat (speaking metaphorically), though very front seat (literally), passenger.

Comment: Not to mention an uncountable number of ships lost that were not piloted by him, but under his command, especially during the first invasion of the Omicronians.

Answer (score 0):

His personal ship, the Nimbus has been destroyed several times. Two examples that immediately come to mind are "A Taste of Freedom" where the Nimbus is chopped in half by a crab like ship, and again in the movie Into the Wild Green Yonder while traversing a giant miniature golf course.

Comment: In most appearances Nimbus was destroyed at the end. I believe that the number is with two digits, but I really wonder how much times exactly? But, I realize it could be difficult to find out, because I doubt that someone has counted that, and there is to much episodes to check it on quick.

Comment: Yes, it would be very difficult to count all the ships he has destroyed.