# Nimbus Battleship

Tags: futurama

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How many battleships has Zapp Brannigan lost?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/19546/how-many-battleships-has-zapp-brannigan-lost)

he Nimbus is the intergalactic flagship of the DOOP fleet. In command of the Nimbus is the 25-Star-General Zapp Brannigan.

How many times did the Nimbus get destroyed?

Comment: gnovice answers this question (he has it listed as 4 times the Nimbus has been seriously damaged or destroyed) in the previous question linked to by NominSim, so this is a duplicate question.

Comment: @onewho: 5 times now. ;)

Comment: I'm only talking about the nimbus